# the probability that exactly 4 dice are sixes given that none are fives.

Tags: probability

My answer key tells me the answer is (10 Choose 4)(1/5)^4 (4/5)^6.

But isn't conditional probability of P(A|B) = P(A and B)/P(B)? Why isn't this answer divided by (5/6)^10? Any help with my intuition? Thanks!

Edit: Sorry, left out some information. It is rolled ten times.

Comment: Did you roll 10 times?  It seems so, but is not clear.

Comment: You failed to indicate how many dice are thrown; I presume $10$, or one die, ten times?

Comment: You can do it your way. But to compute $\Pr(A\cap B)$, the easiest way is $(5/6)^{10}\binom{10}{4}(1/5)^4(4/5)^6$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most straight forward way to interpret that none are fives is simply consider the possible outcomes reduced.  That is, you know each roll was one of $\{1,2,3,4,6\}$.  So knowing this, the probability that exactly four were $6$ is given as
$$ {10 \choose 4} \left( \frac{1}{5} \right) ^4 \left( \frac{4}{5} \right) ^6 $$

If you'd like to use conditional probability, you can write
$$ P(A|B) = \frac{P(AB)}{P(B)} $$
where $P(B) = \left( \frac{5}{6} \right)^{10}$ and $P(AB) = \left( \frac{5}{6} \right)^{10} {10 \choose 4} \left( \frac{1}{5} \right) ^4 \left( \frac{4}{5} \right) ^6 $ which will cancel the factor of $\left( \frac{5}{6} \right)^{10}$ out to give you the answer above :)

Comment: This makes sense to me, but I want to make it work the other way. There must be something wrong with my P(A and B)?

Comment: Aw ok, well what do you have for $P(A$ and $B)$?

Comment: Ah I think I figured it out. It should be

(10 choose 4)(1/6)^4(4/6)^6 / (5/6)^10. This gives the same answer that you have.